# Kotlin extension not recognized in adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have basic extension util for picasso:

```
public val Context.picasso: Picasso 
get() = Picasso.with(this)

public fun ImageView.load(path: String, request: (RequestCreator) -> RequestCreator) {
    request(context.picasso.load(path)).into(this)
}
```

And when I try to call it from imageview context in adapter it's not recognized.

[image]

Same thing with itemView.context.picasso

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your extensions are out of scope (in a different package).
Import your extensions like so:

```
import your.package.picasso
import your.package.load
```

Take a look at [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#scope-of-extensions) for more info.

Comment: thanks for answer. unfortunately there is no such import, I try
to import utils.ImageUtils.load ( import utils.* is not available too).
ImageUtils class with its function is public.

Comment: @Ardi, are your extension functions inside the `ImageUtils` class? I'm not sure they can be. Try putting them outside the class.

Comment: thanks, it works! I don't expect absence of the class.

Comment: Check for `import your.package.extension`, extension of component (ImageView) should be outside of any class @voddan